# Attach hidden value to a visible input

Tags: html

Is there a way to attach some hidden information with an input ??

I have a `<datalist>` of clients, which is autocompleted by client mobile. Currently, the list has the following format:

```
<input placeholder="mobile" list="names" name="name">
<datalist id="names">
 <option value="01234567">Ali Khalid</option>
 <option value="98776421">Ahmed</option>
 ...
</datalist>
```

Now in the post script, I want to know each value's id. Is there a way to attach the client id with each `<option>`??

I know I can make the mobile unique for each client, not allowing nulls (i.e. primary key), but I am looking for a better solution so that the primary key is still ID

Comment: where is the id in ur markup?

Comment: e.g. `<option value="1010100" client_id="5">Name</option>`

Comment: you tagged the question with just "html". do you mean really to achieve this with only html? As you can solve it easily using asp.net controls or using some complex JQuery

Comment: I can use jQuery, javascript, php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I would not think about adding a hidden field to hold id.
Rather I would have an array of JSON objects to hold users data (id, name, and mobile) as follows

```
var array = [
             {
              id:1, 
              name: 'Ali Khalid', 
              mobile:'0123'
             },
             {
              id:2, 
              name: 'Ahmed', 
              mobile:'9877'
             }, 
             //rest of objects
            ]
```

Then lookup that array with the selected value and get the id to use it for server side operations